# Two video sources framerates vary by .01 FPS. Will this cause problems?

Tags: framerate, davinci-resolve

I'm just getting started and have some user-level equipment, not professional grade.

My Sony Handycam outputs MTS and MP4 at 29.97 FPS.

My LG K30 smartphone outputs MP4 at 29.98FPS

Using Davinci Resolve, I notice a slight stutter in my rendered files. Is this .01 FPS difference the cause? If so, how can I get them to match before I import them into the project?

I'm working on a fairly modest laptop with an intel core i5 processor 1.7GHz - 2.4Ghz and 8GB Ram. Video controller just says "Intel(R) HD Graphics Family". I'd assume it uses part of that 8G of ram.

Answer (score 1):

This shouldn't really be a problem and probablly is just a rounding error.
The shutter may come from somewhere else, are the export settings matching the 29.97FPS?

Answer (score 1):

This may be an issue with the Variable Frame Rate (VFR) of either the Sony or LG footage.

You can try two new separate projects with only each of source files at their 'native' framerate and see if either stutters.

You could then try covert the stuttering source footage to Constant Bit Rate (CBR) using software like Handbrake (https://handbrake.fr). Where you can transcode (convert) the footage after setting the **Framerate (FPS)** to 29.97 and selecting **Constant Framerate**.

[image: Handbrake example]